# Publishing QGIS Plugin without giving access to API keys that the plugin relies on

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, authentication, pyqt5

I am building a plugin that requires an API key that I would not like to be shared publicly.

Is there anyway that I can do this?

I am new to QGIS but I know you have to publish your code.

Comment: You can prompt the user to enter their own API key using a dialog. Perhaps save it using [`QgsSettings`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/other/QgsSettings.html) after confirmation by user.